# Instaling Ubuntu on my Dell Inspirion 14 5447

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

After more than 7 years, I am glad to now go for instaling Ubuntu in a laptop of mine. Before was it about not loosing warranty, or being easier to update to a newer version of Windows. I am going forward to version 12.04, since this is the one Dell is mentioning on their support webpage (I don't know why).
I am a smart user only (not a technitian or computer expert). Consider also that I have no sistem installed nowadays. The original hd drive has broken and I have bought a Kingston SSD 120gb as substititute.
Questions:
1) Can or is it better to install a newer version considering the hardware I have?
2) Where can I find the drivers for it?
3) I had download a 12.04.5 version called Desktop CD for 64-bit PC (AMD64) computers (standard download). Even though it says desktop, is it for laptops too? And the 64-bit configuration is it correct too?
4) For instalation, where is the best guide you have? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop?
Looking forward to hearing from you, tks and kind regards,
John.

Comment: I did it :). And even though I still very fresh things with my computer and Ubuntu are very fine and I am glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great to have you onboard John.
I'll try to answer in your given order:

1.
It can indeed sometimes be favorable to try and run some older Linux distribution on old hardware, because those tend to be based on older kernels, which is the layer that communicates between hard- and software in your computer. However, when trying to find your laptop online, I can only find fairly new ones. (e.g. [here](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0%2C2817%2C2475936%2C00.asp?tab=Specs)) Therefore it is hard to tell without really knowing your hardware.

One thing to keep in mind with older Ubuntu versions is the support with security updates. 12.04 will only be supported for about one more year, you can learn more about these support schedules on by checking online for "Ubuntu Wiki LTS". There you can also see that 14.04 will be supported until 2019, which would give you peace for a lot longer.

I would therefore advise you to download the 14.04 LTS version of Ubuntu [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and simply boot that version up on your laptop and instead of installing it right away there will be an option to live test the system. If that works out well and your hardware functions as it should then you can confidently install 14.04 on your laptop.

2.
The drivers will come with your Linux Distribution (in this case Ubuntu) in form of the kernel. No need to search for any drivers on the web.

3.
The desktop image of Ubuntu is correct for use on a laptop. "Desktop" rather means that it is not the server version, which comes without a graphical user interface. If Dell recommends the 64bit image for your Laptop then that should be correct, and it's not like you can destroy anything.

4.
The guide you link there seems to incorporate all the things you need to know.

Comment: Hopfi, Many thanks for your help. Sorry only now getting back in contact, but many other priorities put me away of installing Ubuntu and as a consequence, answering you. I am going to do it now. Going to version 14.04 LTS. Any other suggestion?? Kind regards, John.

Comment: Hopfi, I had just noted that now it is redirecting to download version Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. Can I install it? Requirements say 2ghz minimum.

Comment: Just noticed that this question/topic has been accessed more than two hundred times. Due to that, I just want to mention that all things are fine with my dell 14 5447 and my ubuntu 16.04.2 lts running withing it. Who still worried on doing systems migrations like that, do not wait, go forward. :)